Error when running meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf from hugging face, I don't understand where I am going wrong
The code that I am running is:
import torch
from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceLLM

llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
    context_window=4096,
    max_new_tokens=256,
    generate_kwargs={"temperature": 0.0, "do_sample": False},
    system_prompt = "You need to create proposal documents for the information that we are giving to you. This proposal has to be 5 paragraphs and answered well. If you need more information regarding the topic, you can reply with what furhter information could help",
    ## add the description of what I want it to work on
    query_wrapper_prompt = "<|USER|>{query_str}<|ASSISTANT|>",
    tokenizer_name="meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",
    model_name="meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",
    device_map="auto",
    # uncomment this if using CUDA to reduce memory usage
    model_kwargs={"torch_dtype": torch.float16 , "load_in_8bit":True}
)

The error that I am getting from trying to run this is:
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-0d2d206e16bb> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceLLM
      3 
----> 4 llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
      5     context_window=4096,
      6     max_new_tokens=256,

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/quantizers/quantizer_bnb_8bit.py in validate_environment(self, *args, **kwargs)
     60     def validate_environment(self, *args, **kwargs):
     61         if not (is_accelerate_available() and is_bitsandbytes_available()):
---> 62             raise ImportError(
     63                 "Using `bitsandbytes` 8-bit quantization requires Accelerate: `pip install accelerate` "
     64                 "and the latest version of bitsandbytes: `pip install -i https://pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes`"

ImportError: Using `bitsandbytes` 8-bit quantization requires Accelerate: `pip install accelerate` and the latest version of bitsandbytes: `pip install -i https://pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes`

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
I have tried pip installing the libraries once again and am still getting an error. If you could help with this I would be very appreciative of it.


ImportError: Using bitsandbytes 8-bit quantization requires Accelerate: pip install accelerate and the latest version of bitsandbytes: pip install -i https://pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes

You need to:
pip install accelerate

And then
pip install -i https://pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes

TL;DR
Requires Python >=3.8. Linux distribution (Ubuntu, MacOS, etc.) + CUDA > 10.0.
(CUDA 10.0 is deprecated and only CUDA >= 11.0 will be supported with release 0.39.0)

This is suggesting exactly what’s in the error message from the OP’s question, which they’ve stated they’ve tried to install again, but continue to get the error. The explanation may be useful, but this doesn’t seem to answer the question.
